# IPv6 Virtual Network in Linux

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'm going to do a project based on IPv6 Network. So I need to create a IPv6 Virtual Network in my Linux OS (I use Ubuntu). Also I need to create some virtual hosts in my virtual network and setup static ips (local ips) for each and every host. And I need to run a terminal on each virtual host.

Can I setup that kind of an environment on my Linux OS? Please give me some help to do this.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by virtual host and terminal.

If you just need the network devices, you can use VLANs [Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Howto_use_vlan_.28dot1q.2C_802.1q.2C_trunk.29_.28Etch.2C_Lenny.29)
You basically create sub-interfaces like eth0.5, eth0.6 etc.
Then you can give them a static IP with ifconfig and bind any network service to it. (Thats what I do, as I'm doing something similar to you)

If you need a full virtual host behind that, you can setup several virtual machines (e.g., with VirtualBox) and configure them to be in the same (virtual)network. But I'm afraid I can't give you details on that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some virtualization software for that like Xen, VirtualBox, vmware etc.